# Crystal Reports dynamic image using URL formula

Tags: image, crystal-reports

We want to show an image in a Crystal Report 2008 report, and the URL of the image depends on a field in our database, eg:

`"https://images.somewhere.com/" & {Data.Field} & ".jpg"`

This is supposedly possible using a 'picture location' formula on the Picture object ([as described here](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2010/03/15/crystal-reports-dynamic-images/) and [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552267/display-image-in-crystal-reports-using-url/2554570#2554570)), but we can't get it to work - it just shows the default picture every time.

Is there something we are missing?

Answer (score 4):

Crystal Report **can not access** to Images in machine with HTTPS.

Comment: This saved me a major headache!

Comment: Might this have something to do with trust relationship? Was the web host certificate installed and valid, and trusted by the RAS server? IME most apps that fail to connect to HTTPS (but work fine with HTTP) do so because of failure to properly handle certificates.

Answer (score 2):

maybe a bit late! but this is the answer to why you weren't getting pictures (dynamic ones) to show up on crystal report.  The pictures are assembled with the report form (the blank one) on compile time.  This means when the program code is changed to .exe file that can be run later whatever picture you had then on that form is what is carried over.  No other dynamic pics from urls or from paths.  Getting pictures dynamically on crystal report is a hustle.  Read on things like

- @Picture crystal reports formula
- How to get Pictures dynamically on crystal reports
- How to add Byte() pictures on Crystal Reports

Some of these methods might help.

I am still searching on solid way to add pics to the crystal reports on run time.  So far, nothing short of experimentation here.

Comment: Thanks, can you give the URLs of the pages you were trying to link to?

Answer (score 1):

That's true: Crystal can't deal with https.
Just wanted to add one extra info, which caused some headache to me.
Crystal dynamic images from URLs doesn't work if the image is hosted remotely and the machine that is running the report is connected through a Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Crystal can't access the secure server?  Do the images show if they are stored on your local machine, i.e. `"C:\images\" & {Data.Field} & ".jpg"?`

Comment: It works with pictures stored in local machine, but not with URL